# Lua multiple inputs in table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm new to lua and I have this assignment and one of the questions I'm really stumped on is asking:

"A program that asks the user repeatedly for students' scores, will stop when the user enters a score of 999 then the program should calculate and display the number of scores entered, highest score, lowest score, and the average score. Make sure to display an error message if a score less than zero or more than 100 is entered by user. "

I've been at this all week long and still can't figure out what to do and its due at 11:59pm est. Any insight and direction would be great.

-How do I input multiple values in a growing table scores = {}? Where the size is given by the number of inputs for variable s after the user enters 999 and ends the repeat loop. This is actually my BIGGEST problem.

**My Code:**

```
 local scores = {}, avg


   repeat
    io.write("Enter score(s)")
local s = tonumber(io.read())  --input and convert data type
    print(s, type(s))     --s value, check input type


if(s < 0 or s > 100) then
print("Error.")  
end



    until (s == 999)

for i = 0, #s, 1 do
sum = 0
if s then 
    sum = sum + s
end

end


-- -----------------------------------------------------------Attemps to find a way to put s values in scores table-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--[[scores[#scores+1] = s  ----Attempt 1  
print (scores)

for i = 0, #s, 1 do    ----Attempt 2
    scores{s} = s[i] 
print (i, scores)                                                   --tried a multitude of different ways and
                                                                       --kept getting the same number printed once or memory location of last entered number
end

for i, s in ipairs (scores) do   --Attempt 3
print (i, s)
end

for i = 0, #s, 1 do
sum = 0
if s then 
    sum = sum + s
end

end --]]
 -- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--[[function average(myTable)
local sum = 0

for i in scores do

sum = sum + i
end
return (sum / #scores)
end




print ("The number of values in the table"..#scores)
print ("The average of the scores is "..average(s))
print ("The max value in the table is "..math.max(s))           
print ("The minimum value in the table is "..math.min(s))


  table.maxn(scores), table.minn(scores)
--]]

io.write("Please press enter to continue")
io.read()
```

Comment: Your attempt #1 should have worked, assuming that `s` is not `nil` (it is impossible to store `nil` in Lua tables). What went wrong when you tried that?

Comment: You don't need a table to accumulate those particular statistics. You can keep a running count, sum, max and min. (BTW, if you are submitting your assignment in the U.S. or Canada, you probably should have changed your clock to EDT, so it would be due an hour earlier than 11:59pm EST.)